# Algorithm Analysis of recursion and iteration

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration

I am currently learning about Algorithm Analysis in recursion and iterative functions.

I understand Algorithm Analysis in recursion more so than iterative functions. I am not great at analyzing recursion functions, but I get the jist of it all.

In fact, I am extremely confused when comes to the analysis in iterative functions.

I have searched the site for help on these two topics because I really want to understand and be proficient at Algorithm Analysis. I don't want to just get by. Are there any great sites or good reads that are available to help me understand these topics better in Layman's terms?

I have read about Knuth's book Concrete Mathematics and bought a copy. Are there any other sites or books that may teach these topics better or that I can find and practice online?

Just for example purposes, a practice question I am confused about was a problem like this:

```
for(i = 1 to n)
{
    for(l = 1 to i)
    for(j = 1 to 3)
    {
         2 operations 
    for(k = 1 to i)
         3 operations
    }
}
```

I get where to start, but after the initial step all the wheels fall off for me. I will gladly accept any help in directing me in the right direction about these topics.

Thank you all for your time and help.

(I apologize if this too broad of a topic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you understand the thing.

http://discrete.gr/complexity/

And Knuth's book and Intoduction to Algorithms by CLRS are the bibles of algorithms. If you want a brief knowledge in algorithms, I personally suggest those two books.

Answer (score 1):

As a tip for iterative algorithms/functions:

Most of the cases your concern is only one thing: the input size i.e. `n`. So at glance check how far would a function goes when `n` is very large. You can roughly estimate the complexity in terms of `n`.

For a resource, I found myself enjoying reading [this](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/everything.pdf) lecture notes (its a book more than notes).